# Remote Management/VNC Mac OSX Server 10.6 from Windows Server 2008

Tags: remote-desktop, mac-osx-server, vnc

What is the most compatible/reliable software to remote manage an osx server using windows server?

I tried to activate the remote management from osx server then use remote desktop login from windows(failed)
Tried to activate built in vnc server from osx server then use vnc client from windows(failed)
tried to install osxvnc server(vine server) on osx then use either tightvnc or ultravnc on windows (connects but after sometime disconnect)

PS. I would prefer a free software for both servers.

Comment: VNC should work, you just need to fiddle with the encoding settings a bit - I can't remember which one you need but IIRC there's 3 or 4 choices and only 1 is stable for the Mac-->windows combination.

Comment: I also tried realvnc. Based on google searches, many suggests to use Hextile for format and encoding(didn't work for me).. But the problem is that with any VNC Viewer I use, I connect to the osx Server then after like 20secs it disconnects. After I reconnect, it disconnects again after 20secs.

Comment: Take a look at your OS X server's system logs, is there anything interesting going on around when you connect and right before/during/after you disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

Install OSXVNC, it works from the beginning with almost any Windows client

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/